# Send message to specific channel with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

I want to send a greeting message to an "welcome" text channel, whenever a new user joins the server (guild).

The problem I'm facing is that, when I find the wanted channel, I will receive the channel with the type `GuildChannel`.

Since `GuildChannel` has no `send()` function, I'm not able to send the message. But I can't find a way to find the `TextChannel`, so I'm stuck here.

How can I get to the `TextChannel` so that I'm able to use the `send()` message? Below the code I'm using by now:

```
// Get the log channel (change to your liking) 
const logChannel = guild.channels.find(123456); 
if (!logChannel) return;

// A real basic message with the information we need. 
logChannel.send('Hello there!'); // Property 'send' does not exist on type 'GuildChannel'
```

I'm using version 11.3.0 of discord.js

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2957) I've found the solution to my problem.

I need to use a [Type Guard](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html) to narrow down the correct type.

My code now is this:

```
// Get the log channel
const logChannel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.id == 123456);

if (!logChannel) return;

// Using a type guard to narrow down the correct type
if (!((logChannel): logChannel is TextChannel => logChannel.type === 'text')(logChannel)) return;

logChannel.send(`Hello there! ${member} joined the server.`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe for latecomers who are still looking for an answer this worked for me

```
let channel = client.channels.get("channelid") as Discord.TextChannel;
channel.send("what you want to send to that channel");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`GuildChannel#isText()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=isText) method to type guard before invoking `send`.

Example:

```
if (channel.isText()) {
   await channel.send('...');
}
```

Or:

```
if (!channel.isText()) return;
await channel.send('...');
```

Answer (score 1):

Discord v14

```
const channel: TextChannel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId) as TextChannel;                
channel.send('test')
```

If you have problems with cache, you can use

```
const channel: TextChannel = await client.channels.fetch(channel.channelId) as TextChannel;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
let channel = client.guilds.get('your-guild-id').channels.get('your-channel-id');
channel.send("it worked");
```

(client is the discord client). your code should work if you change `find` to `get` and put the channel id in some single quotes. Well, it works for me.

Comment: There is no `get()` function in the GuildChannel class. I get that this would work with plain javascript, but I want to use typescript. Therefor I'm bound to the classes provided.

Comment: `get()` is a discord.js collection function, its not part of the GuildChanel class.
`guild.channels` returns a collection so it should work. I think

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you?

Code:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    let channel = member.guild.channels.find('name', 'welcome');
    let memberavatar = member.user.avatarURL
        if (!channel) return;
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setThumbnail(memberavatar)
            .addField(':bust_in_silhouette: | name : ', `${member}`)
            .addField(':microphone2: | Welcome!', `Welcome to the server, ${member}`)
            .addField(':id: | User :', "**[" + `${member.id}` + "]**")
            .addField(':family_mwgb: | Your are the member', `${member.guild.memberCount}`)
            .addField("Name", `<@` + `${member.id}` + `>`, true)
            .addField('Server', `${member.guild.name}`, true )
            .setFooter(`**${member.guild.name}**`)
            .setTimestamp()
        channel.sendEmbed(embed);
});
```

Comment: There is no `sendEmbed()` function in the GuildChannel class. I get that this would work with plain javascript, but I want to use typescript. Therefor I'm bound to the classes provided.