# Sending messages on Discord Bot start / on schedule using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I've been building a Discord Bot in TypeScript for myself and a group of friends to use. I'm trying to send a message on client ready that's completely independent of any interactions with the bot that the users have (messages, errors, logging in, etc) so I want the message to send as soon as the client is ready.

I've seen some solutions already on sending messages on client ready and scheduling ([Send scheduled message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47548081/discord-js-send-scheduled-message)) so that is not a problem but the main problem I have with these solutions is that the discord.js type GuildChannels (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel) does not actually include the send method unless it's of type TextChannel (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel). However, the type that's given by client.channels.get(channelId) returns a GuildChannel (that's possibly of type text).

So an example of my code looks like this.

```js
import { Client } from 'discord.js';

import { BOT_SECRET_TOKEN, FOX_GUILD_ID, FOXBOT_CHANNEL } from './secret.json';

const client = new Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Connected as ${client.user.tag}`);

  const foxGuild = client.guilds.get(FOX_GUILD_ID);
  if (!foxGuild) {
    console.log('Guild not found');

    return;
  }

  const foxbotChannel = foxGuild.channels.get(FOXBOT_CHANNEL);
  if (!foxbotChannel) {
    console.log('Channel not found');

    return;
  }

  foxbotChannel.message('I am ready for service!');
});
```

The line

```
  foxbotChannel.message('I am ready for service!');
```

Will give me this error

```
src/index.ts(26,17): error TS2339: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'GuildChannel'.
```

I have also tried importing TextChannel and initiating foxbotChannel like so

```js
foxbotChannel: TextChannel = foxGuild.channels.get(FOXBOT_CHANNEL);
```

But also get an error saying that the type GuildChannel is missing a bunch of properties.

So my question is, how do I convert GuildChannel to a TextChannel so that I'm able to send messages through that or, how do I find the TextChannel through client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Classes**

The `TextChannel` class extends the `GuildChannel` class which extends `Channel`, meaning you could think of them as sub-classes: `Channel` ==> `GuildChannel` ==> `TextChannel`.

Everything that works for `Channel` will work for `GuildChannel`, everything that works for `GuildChannel` will work for `TextChannel`, plus the additional properties and methods listed for each.

**Update:** To get the right type (`TextChannel`), you can use TypeGuards as shown in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53608094).

---

**Property 'message' does not exist**

`message()` is not a valid method. Use `send()`, like so:

```js
foxbotChannel.send('I am ready for service!');
```

Comment: Oh, so I just tried using send but I'm still getting error because send is a TextChannel method. Since TextChannel is a sub-class of GuildChannel, that means that TextChannel will have additional methods that GuildChannel does not have, send being one of them right?
I'm still getting
`src/index.ts(26,17): error TS2339: Property 'send' does not exist on type 'GuildChannel'.`

Comment: Correct. See [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send).

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using 11.4.2 for Discord.js.

So in this case right now, since foxbotChannel is a GuildChannel, is there a way I can use that to create a TextChannel?

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using a string for the ID and not a number? Also, make sure the channel exists. Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce this with my testing. If the channel is a text channel, `channels.get()` *should* be returning a `TextChannel`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a string for the guild and channel ID. How would it know that it's a TextChannel before compiling though? If I'm just using .get(), it shouldn't know until runtime right?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use find a channel with id like this.

We find the server and after the channel and then send a message.

```
client.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.id === 'your serveur id here')
  .channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === 'the channel id here')
  .send('bot on')
```